# this loader is repeating three times?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<style>
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: url('images/page-loader.gif');
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
```

html

i m using this loader code for my website but it is repeating itself three times.. i also used no repeat css but it is not workin

Comment: Share a fiddle or working example.

Comment: and the html???

Comment: without the html we can't do much to help you.

Comment: this is html    ....  <div class="loader"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example of what you want.. `

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".bg").fadeOut('slow');
})
```

```css
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.loader {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fjSD.gif');
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: -21px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: change the order of background-repeat, put it after background

Comment: but i want to use my gif from the folder which is not working... please help

Comment: just replace === background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fjSD.gif'); with your structure === background: url('images/page-loader.gif');

Comment: no sir it is not working.. it is supporting only your image

Comment: can you show your folder structure.. May be you are giving wrong path..

Comment: sorry .. i was using large image and the width & height is defined small in css ..now it is working fine thanku

Comment: the code is working fine on localhost but on server after loading page it continous to 100%  because i m using %ge bar .. but how to stop it when page loads completely

Answer (score 0):

you need to atleast use a `div`to show the loader. Please find the details below,

html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>

<div class="loader">
</div>
```

js

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

css

```
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/xTk9ZvMnbIiIew7IpW/giphy.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

i have put a sample image.

Comment: <div class="loader"></div>  this is the div